# java- best way to continuously monitor a table in db for new rows being added

Tags: scheduling, job-scheduling

In a java app (not a web app) I want to monitor continuously a table in SQL Server database, and the moment a new row is added, I want to schedule a "job" corresp. to that row. Similarly, if an existing row is deleted (in same table) then I also want corresp. scheduled job to be cancelled.

I do understand how to schedule a job or remove a scheduled job-- what I want to know is, how do I continuously monitor the table for additions/deletions in that table (so that I can schedule/remove a job)?

I want the above to be done continuously from the moment this app is deployed on its server. (There will be other code too in that app to run the scheduled jobs, etc).

Any guides or howto's will be very helpful. I understand that Java 7 has something called "WatchService" however from what I read that is useful to monitor any files being added/deleted from a specific folder...I am looking for something that can be applied in a similar way for monitoring additions/deletions in a table in database.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can query the table periodically using the SQL count() function -

`SELECT count(1) FROM table_name`

and check if the count changes.

Comment: ok, but what I am looking for is a easy-to-use mechanism to periodically query the table-- just like "WatchService" can be used to watch a folder for files being added/deleted-- and this mechanism should always be monitoring the table- and there will be other code too in the same app which can be invoked as usual...

Comment: I'm not sure if Java `Timer` and `TimerTask` will fulfill your requirement.